# How to ensure consistent article reference format with missing fields?

Tags: bibtex, elsarticle

I am trying to cite a bibtex `@article` that does not have the `volume` or `number` fields. It is appearing like this:

> Dogg, C., & Bird, A. (2020). Article title. Journal Name, (pp.
>   100-101).

I want it to appear like the other journal articles, like this:

> Dogg, C., & Bird, A. (2020). Article title. *Journal Name*, 100–102.

For reference, other journal articles are appearing like this:

> Dogg, C., & Bird, A. (2020). Article title. *Journal Name, 42*, 1,
>   100–102.

How can I do that?

I am using the APA `\bibliographystyle{model5-names}\biboptions{authoryear}` of the `elsarticle` class.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: All current Elsevier bib styles ignore the `number` field for entries of type `@article`. If your entry lacks a `number` field, it's of no consequence for the way the bib style attempts to format the entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if a bibliographic entry of type `@article` doesn't come with a valid `volume` field, you may want to double-check that the `@article` entry type is indeed the appropriate choice for this entry.

Second, Elsevier's `model5-names` bibliography style is no longer distributed with TeXLive and isn't available on the CTAN either. The bibliography style file *is* still available on Overleaf; however, I wouldn't put much stock in an Elsevier bib style that appears to have been abandoned by its creator (Elsevier). Aside: I'm assuming you wish to employ the `model5-names` bib style because you're getting ready to submit a paper to an Elsevier-stable journal. If that's not the case, you should probably re-examine the use case for `model5-names`...

Third, assuming it is indeed appropriate to employ the `@article` entry type for the entry at hand, you may want to switch to the fairly similar (but still supported) `elsarticle-harv` bibliography style, as it already does what you're looking to achieve in terms of the display of the `pages` field. (My hunch is that you're not the only one who dislikes the formatting that's applied by `model5-names`...) Since the `elsarticle-harv` bib style also expects a non-empty `volume` field, you should change `journal = "Journal Name",` to `journal = "Journal Name\ignorespaces",` to make sure that there's no whitespace gap between the journal name and the subsequent comma.

[image]

```
\documentclass[authoryear,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set margins suitably
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv} %{model5-names}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@article{dg20-a,
   author  = "Carla Dogg and Anna Bird",
   year    = 2020,
   title   = "Article Title A",
   journal = "Journal Name",
   pages   = "100-101",
   note    = ". Note the gap after ``Journal Name''",
}
@article{dg20-b,
   author  = "Carla Dogg and Anna Bird",
   year    = 2020,
   title   = "Article Title B",
   journal = "Journal Name\ignorespaces",
   pages   = "100-101",
   note    = ". The gap is gone.",
}
@article{dg20-c,
   author  = "Carla Dogg and Anna Bird",
   year    = 2020,
   title   = "Article Title C",
   journal = "Journal Name",
   volume  = 1,
   pages   = "100-101",
   note    = "An entry with a non-empty ``volume'' field",
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\citep{dg20-a,dg20-b,dg20-c}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```